# Streamwriter not adding text to file?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have the following code:

```
If line = Nothing Then
    MsgBox("Login failed.")
        Using sw As New StreamWriter(File.Open(Index.strLogPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)) ' open or create a new file at our path
        sw.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End) ' append new users to the end
        sw.AutoFlush = True
        sw.WriteLine("line is nothing")
        sw.Flush()
        sw.Close()
        End Using

End If
```

My line = nothing condition is met, the msgbox pops up letting me know, but the file is not created. If the file is there, nothing is added to it.

I have checked the path validity, and ensured that applications have permission there, everything I can think of isn't working, and to make it more frustrating there are no errors! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the [File.AppendAllText Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? And what is the type of `line`? You should use `Is` rather than `=` to compare to `Nothing` in VB.NET. Are you confusing an empty String with Nothing? There's [String.IsNullOrEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx) available.

Comment: If you do `MsgBox(Index.strLogPath)` in that same code, does it show the desired filename?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes, it shows me the exact path to the txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you know that the `File` class already has a utility method to do exactly that?

```
File.AppendAllText(Index.strLogPath, "line is nothing")
```

Should be as simple as that. :)

**EDIT**

If you insist on managing the file stream yourself, try this:

```
    Using sw As New StreamWriter(File.Open(Index.strLogPath, FileMode.Append)) ' open or create a new file at our path
        sw.WriteLine("line is nothing")
    End Using
```

Points of interest:

- Use `FileMode.Append` instead of `OpenOrCreate`
- No need to flush or close. This is done automatically when you leave the "using" block.